# Using two curves to make a rounded groove

Tags: modeling

I am having trouble making a specific shape. Specifically, It is ellipsoid with an ogive cross section (for those of you who don’t know what either of those are, an Ogive, is the shape of a rocket nose cone, while an ellipsoid is a fancy term for a 3D oval). I am trying to make this as smooth and even as possible, yet every option that I try does not work due to the unevenness of the curves. I have the both the curves for the Y and Z axis mapped out (Fig. 2 and 3), but the x axis curve is uneven thoughout (The curve grows and shrinks depending on how far from the center on both the y and z axis you travel, Fig. 1 shows this pretty well).

*As a sidenote, I come from a engineering and CAD modeling background, so vertex modeling is new in that I don’t have as easy access to the complex shapes used in programs like Solidworks or Fusion 360.*

Any help or suggestions are welcome.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean the curve grows and shrinks? The visual representation in pixels? That's like when in Adobe Illustrator you've scaled the view so small you can't differentiate between 0.25 pt, 0.5 pt and 0.75 pt lines - they might be all one pixel thick. And if a line isn't vertical or horizontal but diagonal or curved, trying to show that with the pixel resolution of a monitor is not easy. Your curves have a theoretical thickness of 0 as long as you don't add geometry, and 0 is hard to show if you have a fixed monitor resolution and the need to visualize the path of the curve.

Comment: Is [this](https://imgur.com/a/QjIKKkV) the shape you mean?